# Laravel model validation: How to allow only ONE related model

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have a model `Training` with a recording

[image]

In my model `Observation`, I have to note the feedback of the training.

The desired behavior is to allow only **one** observation per training. For example, if I have 3 trainings, I can enter 3 observations. My problem is that my code allows me to add several observations for each training. I would like to better handle that with an error message.

[image]

Here is an idea of my code for now

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'instruction' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'fk_student' => 'required'
  ]);

  $instruction = $request->get('instruction'); 
  $description = $request->get('description');
  $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');

  $trainings = Training::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->first();

  if(!isset($trainings)){ 
    return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                     ->with('error', 'No training, no observation! ');
  } else {
    Observation::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                     ->with('success', 'Add');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the desired behavior? I think what you want is this: If a training already has an observation, you cannot add another observation to it. Or in other words, a training can have a maximum of 1 observation. Do I have that right?

Comment: Hey @user11124425, I'm trying to help you, but you haven't given enough information. Answer my questions above and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hi @Vince, sorry, yes that's it ... thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok @user11124425, I have edited your question to clarify the desired behavior. If I got something wrong, feel free to rollback any edits that you don't agree with. This should make it easier for you to get help with this. I will circle back to it later today if it still hasn't been answered.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Vince, I am stuck... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can solve this issue. I'll offer three solutions here, but keep in mind that you can choose to implement one of the three, some combination of the three, or something completely different altogether.

---

**Method 1: Frontend**

Personally, I think this is the best solution. It is the simplest to implement, and it yields the desired outcome. All you have to do is disable the "Add" button if a `Training` already has an `Observation` recorded:

*your-view.blade.php:*

```html
<h1>Listing Observations</h1>

<!-- Observations Table -->

<button{{ $training->observations()->exists() ? ' disabled' : '' }}>Add</button>
```

This is going to be sufficient for 99.999% of all users of this application. Of course, a savvy user could still submit a request in spite of the button being disabled. In my (cynical) opinion, I'm not going to bother to "fail elegantly" for a user who attempts to circumvent the system.

But that's up to you. You could just implement this method and call it good. If you decide you want the system to be more robust, you can implement either method 2 or method 3.

> **NOTE**: In my opinion, if you choose to implement method 2 or 3, ***you should still also implement method 1***. It's super simple to implement, and it provides a much nicer UX than allowing the user to complete the `Observation` form, and then telling them that they are only allowed to create one `Observation`.

---

**Method 2: Backend – Eloquent**

Eloquent allows you to [query the existence](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) of a related model. That means you can check to see if the `Training` already has a corresponding `Observation` before you create one.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'instruction' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'fk_student' => 'required'
  ]);

  $instruction = $request->get('instruction'); 
  $description = $request->get('description');
  $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');

  $trainings = Training::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->first();

  if(!isset($trainings)){ 
    return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                     ->with('error', 'No training, no observation! ');
  }

  if ($trainings->observations()->exists()) {
    /******************************************************************************
     * I'm returning a plain text response. Depending on your front end code, it
     * might make more sense to return a JSON response. Whatever response type you
     * choose, make sure that you respond with an HTTP error code. I think
     * 400 – Bad Request makes the most sense).
     ******************************************************************************
     */
    return response('An Observation already exists for this Training', 400)
           ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  }

  // If we make it to this point, it is safe to go ahead and create the Observation
  Observation::create($request->all());

  return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                   ->with('success', 'Add');
}
```

---

**Method 3: Backend – Database**

Finally, you could let the database handle this for you. The idea behind this method is that you create a database constraint that limits the number of `Observations` per `Training` to one. With that constraint in place, you process the form submission with the assumption that everything is perfect.

However, since everything is ***not*** going to always be perfect, you must surround your code with a `try/catch` block, and handle the exception that the database will throw.

```php
/****************************************************************
 * You can add this to a new or an existing database migration.
 ****************************************************************
 */
public function up()
{
  Schema::table('observations', function($table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('training_id')
          ->unique()
          ->nullable();
  });
}
```

*YourController.php*

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'instruction' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'fk_student' => 'required'
  ]);

  $instruction = $request->get('instruction'); 
  $description = $request->get('description');
  $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');

  $trainings = Training::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->first();

  if(!isset($trainings)){ 
    return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                     ->with('error', 'No training, no observation! ');
  }

  try {
    Observation::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                     ->with('success', 'Add');
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    /******************************************************************************
     * You shouldn't *really* return `$e->getMessage()` to the user. Just return
     * an error message that makes sense for the action the user attempted.
     ******************************************************************************
     */
    return response($e->getMessage(), 400)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  }
}
```

Comment: Waaaaawwwww thank you a lot Vince, for your code and your time. My proble is solved. thank you a lot. :-)

Comment: No problem – glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

make unique the foreign key on table observations:

```
$table->bigInteger('training_id')->unsigned()->unique();
```

and validate 
'unique:observations,training_id'